# Search a string and alter /replace string after "="

Tags: shell, awk, sed

Suppose I am in following directory  `A/B/C/prop` and need to check  `e0`and `e1` files out of other 100 files.In these two file i have following entries:

```
$DBConnection_target=targetname
$DBConnection_source1=sourcename
```

I need to change `targetname` and `sourcename` only and string that will be used, taken from Keyboard(read).
These string may occur more than 2-3 times.

Comment: Suppose you are paying someone to solve this for you. Or suppose you are showing us what have you tried and how you failed, and suppose someone's willing to help.

Comment: What are `e0` and `e1`?

Comment: The question is not at all clear, but it appears that you have two files named `e0` and `e1` in which you wish to replace certain text strings.  Use `sed`.

Comment: sorry.But i am new to this forum and also to shell scripting.Thats why i couldnot clear the situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed` to perform the replacements in the two files, `e0` and `e1`, as shown below:

```
# set what you want the source and target to be changed to here:
newSource=foo 
newTarget=bar

sed -i 's/\($DBConnection_target\)=.*$/\1='"$newTarget"'/;s/\($DBConnection_source1\)=.*$/\1='"$newSource"'/' e0 e1
```

Comment: plz provide simpler command for :  a)search two required files out of many  b) edit only those 2 files for the following variables :$DBConnection_target=targetname
$DBConnection_source1=sourcename .....                                need to change target name and source name only for these 2 variables.I will be using this command on other server to perform action.

Comment: thanks  dogbane ... but i need to take newsource and newtarget from keyboard "read newsource" will be working correctly if i use ? or kindly suggest other way.